# Sum appearing twice

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've got a table which has a grouping on a category type and a total/sum on each category type. If the category table contents spans across multiple pages, then it'll show the total's twice, with both amounts the same.

i.e.

```
Category Type

(page 1)
1
2
Total =  3
(page 2)
3
Total = 3
```

So the total of 3 on page 3 is appearing on page 1. Not sure how this can be removed?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. On the static property on the total, needed to change the Keep Together property from Before to After